# Variations, Deleting from target is not re-creating pages

Tags: 2013, publishing, variations

I have deleted documents from both source and target sites. I am doing a re-migration of contents. For the folders and documents that were recreated, they were not recreated in the target site.

My setting is set to create everywhere and recreate pages.

I have tried to use update all targets in a single page and it tells me that no target variations of this item exists to update.